# Getting a strange bug in jxBrowser

Tags: jxbrowser

So this is a strange one.  My code does a bunch a things that are hard to explain (but if necessary I´ll try to explain), but the following works:

```
var res = data.delete_if (function(key, value) { return key == "a"; })
```

but the following crashes:

```
data.delete_if (function(key, value) { return key == "a"; })
```

So, the fact that I do not save the result of the delete_if function crashes the browser with the following stack trace:

```
Error: test: B environment should proxy a Ruby hash. (MDArraySolTest):     Java::JavaLang::IllegalStateException: Channel stream was closed before response     has been received.
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java/lang/reflect/Method.java:498) org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirectWithExceptionHandling(org/jruby/javasupport/JavaMethod.java:453)
```

Any ideas of why this happens?  Any solutions?  I can provide more information if needed.

EDIT1:

Doing some more tests I found out that the error occurs only if the call to data.delete_if is the last statement on the script.  If I add for example: console.log(""); after the call, everything works fine.

Thanks

Comment: Just migrated from jxBrowser 6.5 to jxBrowser 6.6.1 and the bug is gone!  Everything is now fine.